# How to hide divs on hover?

Tags: html, css, header

I've got a header for my site that looks like this:

```
.header-cont {
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
}
.header {
    height:50px;
    background:#F0F0F0;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    width:950px;
    margin:0px auto;
}
.header-button {
    background: #73e3eb;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #73e3eb, #5ec9d1);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #73e3eb, #5ec9d1);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #73e3eb, #5ec9d1);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #73e3eb, #5ec9d1);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #73e3eb, #5ec9d1);
    -webkit-border-radius: 13;
    -moz-border-radius: 13;
    border-radius: 13px;
    font-family: Lora;
    color: #6293ad;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 20px 15px 10px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.clearfix:after {
    display:block;
    clear:both;
}
.menu-wrap {
    width:100%;
    box-shadow:0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background:#3e3436;
}
.menu {
    width:1000px;
    margin:0px auto;
}
.menu li {
    margin:0px;
    list-style:none;
    font-family:'Ek Mukta';
}
.menu a {
    transition:all linear 0.15s;
    color:#919191;
}
.menu li:hover > a, .menu .current-item > a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#be5b70;
}
.menu .arrow {
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:0%;
}
.menu > ul > li {
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    font-size:19px;
}
.menu > ul > li > a {
    padding:10px 40px;
    display:inline-block;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
.menu > ul > li:hover > a, .menu > ul > .current-item > a {
    background:#2e2728;
}
.menu li:hover .sub-menu {
    z-index:1;
    opacity:1;
}
.sub-menu {
    width:150px;
    padding:5px 0px;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0px;
    z-index:-1;
    opacity:0;
    transition:opacity linear 0.15s;
    box-shadow:0px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background:#2e2728;
}
.sub-menu li {
    display:block;
    font-size:16px;
}
.sub-menu li a {
    padding:10px 30px;
    display:block;
}
.sub-menu li a:hover, .sub-menu .current-item a {
    background:#3e3436;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div class="header-cont">
            <div class="header">
                <div class="menu-wrap">
                    <nav class="menu">
                        <ul class="clearfix">
                            <li class="current-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><span class="arrow">&#9660;</span>Sites</a>
                                <ul class="sub-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Site A</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Site B</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Site C</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Site D</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Sorry for the long code, but there it is. My problem is that when you hover over the area below the 'Sites' item, the div that is the dropdown list shows. I'd like to change it so that it only shows when you hover on 'Sites', but I'm not sure how. Anybody out there know?

Comment: if the answer below helped you, be sure to mark it as accepted (click the check mark next to it) so that others know that it's useful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the `opacity` property, you should use the `visibility` property. The `opacity` property simply makes the element see-through. The `visibility` property hides the element entirely, but keeps the spacing of the element in the document's normal flow.

**[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/v7bmhs1g/)**

```
.menu li:hover .sub-menu {
    visibility: visible;
}

.sub-menu {
    width:150px;
    padding:5px 0px;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0px;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition:opacity linear 0.15s;
    box-shadow:0px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background:#2e2728;
}
```

You also don't need the `z-index` property.

Alternatively, you could use `display: none;` and `display: block;` as well, which does the same thing as the `visibility` property, except that it doesn't keep the spacing in the document's normal flow.